# Can the following code be shortened into a "ForLoop"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to shorten the following code into a "for loop" or anything of the sort? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var barOneValue = $('.barOne-value').val();
    var barTwoValue = $('.barTwo-value').val();
    var barThreeValue = $('.barThree-value').val();
    var barFourValue = $('.barFour-value').val();
    var barFiveValue = $('.barFive-value').val();
    $('.barOne').attr('percentValue', barOneValue);
    $('.barTwo').attr('percentValue', barTwoValue);
    $('.barThree').attr('percentValue', barThreeValue);
    $('.barFour').attr('percentValue', barFourValue);
    $('.barFive').attr('percentValue', barFiveValue);
});
```

Comment: Yes: if you rename your classes to use integer values (".bar1" instead of "barOne")

Comment: .. or use common classes and traverse by index.

Comment: Or use a different selector. You could make a small function to convert 1 to 'One' etc. and Use it in your loop.

Comment: Thanks all. Does anyone have a code example of how that would work please? Appreciated as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can make a function to help:

```
function int2Word(i){
  var map = ["Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"];
  return map[i];
}
```

Then make your loop:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
   for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++){
     $('.bar' + int2Word(i)).attr('percentValue', $('.bar' + int2Word(i) + '-value').val());
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate he time.

Comment: Glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'].forEach(function(item) {
    $('.bar' + item).attr('percentValue', $('.bar'+ item +'-value').val());
});
```